# Getting Error : A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Abc.Models.ProductItem'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm going for the edit data by ProuctId.i have 2 table like Product and productitems.so i m click on edit go for the id by getting data but that time i m fetch data by id in the product table is getting propare but after going for the list productitems data getting like this error.

this is my class ProductItmes:

```
[Table("ProductItems ")]
public class ProductItems 
  {
   [Key]
public int id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Products")]
public int pid {get; set;}

public int Qty { get; set; }

public Decimal Rate { get; set; }

public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
 }
```

this is my api method:

```
public ActionResult GetProductByid(int id)
{

 var Pro = db.Product.Find(id);
 var ProItemList = db.Promotion_ctc.Where(x => x.pid == Pro.id).ToList();//here i am getting list of items by productid

 var Details = new
 {
    Pro.id,
    Pro.name,
    Pro.image_url,
    ProItemList 
     };

    return Json(new { data = Details });            
  }
```

idk where is my problem any one know please let me know.

Comment: `var ProItemList = db.Promotion_ctc.Where(...` is not throwing the error - its the `return Json(....` code because `ProductItems` contains `Products` and `Products` contains `ProductItems`.

Comment: so how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with MVC and Entity Framework, there are cases where we make our child entities reference the parent, like you did, by declaring this property here:

```
public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
```

it's ok for entity framework, but it's not when you try to serialize this.

What's going on:

- The serializer will try to serialize the parent, which has a collection of `ProductItem`.
- The serializer tries to serialize each child.
- The child has a reference to parent, so the serializer tries to serialize the parent again.
- Infinite loop.

That's why people use `ViewModels`. Instead of just returning your entities from your action, project them into a view model, and return it. Actually, you're returning an anonymous object containing a `ProItemList`, which I'd guess it's a `List` of `ProductItems`. Just create a view model for it:

```
public class ProductItemViewModel 
{

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId {get; set;}

    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public Decimal Rate { get; set; }

    // public virtual Products Products { get; set; } NO PRODUCT HERE
 }
```

...then fix your action to return a `List` of `ProductItemViewModel`, instead of returning directly `ProductItems`, like this:

```
var ProItemList = db.Promotion_ctc.Where(x => x.pid == Pro.id)
.Select(i => new ProductItemViewModel
{
    ItemId = i.ItemId,
    ProductId = i.ProductId,
    Qty = i.Qty,
    Rate = i.Rate
})
.ToList();

var Details = new
{
    Pro.id,
    Pro.name,
    Pro.image_url,
    ProItemList 
     };

    return Json(new { data = Details });            
}
```

Comment: hi alisson i have add one more filed date in Promotion_ctc class as string datatype and in database also date as a string datatype and i m add Date = i.Date but here i want to ToString() in format given but that time get error so have you idea about it this

Comment: in my html input type date so here my date is not filed so please can you help me?

Comment: @coderwill hmm, it's kinda awkward applying `.ToString()` to something which is already a string. Either you have to convert it to a `DateTime` before using `.ToString()`, or change your field to be a `DateTime` instead of string (in both class and database). Also, you should apply `.ToString` after the `.ToList()`, otherwise EF6 will try to execute this `.ToString()` in database, and it won't know how to convert it to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

send only required columns to ui

like this

```
 var passToUi = from s in listResult
                select new { s.Id, s.Name };

 return Json(passToUi, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```